# Heroku golang sample application failed

Tags: heroku, github, go

I am creating sample application on heroku as per documentation [getting-started-with-go](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-go)

It works till Step 3 the first deployment ([deploy-the-app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-go#deploy-the-app))

Problem starts when dependency are added at ([push-local-changes](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-go#push-local-changes))

**Commands Executed**

```
go version
heroku login
go get github.com/heroku/go-getting-started/cmd/...
cd %GOPATH%/src/github.com/heroku/go-getting-started
git remote -v
heroku create
git push heroku master
heroku open
heroku ps:scale web=1

go get -u github.com/tools/godep
godep restore
go get -u github.com/russross/blackfriday

notepad Godeps/Godeps.json
notepad cmd\go-getting-started\main.go
godep save ./...


go install ./...
heroku local

git add -A .
git commit -m "Markdown demo dependency"
git push heroku master
heroku open mark
```

**Output**

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>go version
go version go1.6 windows/amd64

C:\Windows\system32>heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: 01.mandar@gmail.com
Password (typing will be hidden):
Logged in as 01.mandar@gmail.com

C:\Windows\system32>go get github.com/heroku/go-getting-started/cmd/...

C:\Windows\system32>cd %GOPATH%/src/github.com/heroku/go-getting-started

c:\Go\src\github.com\heroku\go-getting-started>git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/heroku/go-getting-started (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/heroku/go-getting-started (push)

c:\Go\src\github.com\heroku\go-getting-started>heroku create
Creating app... done, stack is cedar-14
https://lit-lake-35772.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/lit-lake-35772.git

c:\Go\src\github.com\heroku\go-getting-started>git push heroku master
Counting objects: 353, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (225/225), done.
Writing objects: 100% (353/353), 203.07 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 353 (delta 70), reused 353 (delta 70)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Go app detected
remote: -----> Checking Godeps/Godeps.json file.
remote: -----> Installing go1.6... done
remote: -----> Running: go install -v -tags heroku ./...
remote: github.com/heroku/go-getting-started/vendor/gopkg.in/bluesuncorp/validator.v5
remote: github.com/heroku/go-getting-started/vendor/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/render
remote: github.com/heroku/go-getting-started/vendor/github.com/manucorporat/sse
remote: github.com/heroku/go-getting-started/vendor/github.com/mattn/go-colorable
remote: github.com/heroku/go-getting-started/vendor/golang.org/x/net/context
remote: github.com/heroku/go-getting-started/vendor/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/binding
remote: github.com/heroku/go-getting-started/vendor/github.com/mattn/go-isatty
remote: github.com/heroku/go-getting-started/vendor/github.com/gin-gonic/gin
remote: github.com/heroku/go-getting-started/cmd/go-getting-started
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 3.1M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v3
remote:        https://lit-lake-35772.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/lit-lake-35772.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master

c:\Go\src\github.com\heroku\go-getting-started>heroku open

c:\Go\src\github.com\heroku\go-getting-started>go get -u github.com/tools/godep

c:\Go\src\github.com\heroku\go-getting-started> godep restore

c:\Go\src\github.com\heroku\go-getting-started>
c:\Go\src\github.com\heroku\go-getting-started>go get -u github.com/russross/blackfriday

c:\Go\src\github.com\heroku\go-getting-started>notepad Godeps/Godeps.json

c:\Go\src\github.com\heroku\go-getting-started>notepad cmd\go-getting-started\main.go

c:\Go\src\github.com\heroku\go-getting-started>godep save ./...

c:\Go\src\github.com\heroku\go-getting-started>notepad Godeps/Godeps.json

c:\Go\src\github.com\heroku\go-getting-started>
c:\Go\src\github.com\heroku\go-getting-started>go install ./...

c:\Go\src\github.com\heroku\go-getting-started>heroku local
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
[OKAY] Trimming display Output to 98 Columns
10:01:41 AM web.1 |  [GIN-debug] [WARNING] Running in "debug" mode. Switch to "release" mode in production.
10:01:41 AM web.1 |   - using env:      export GIN_MODE=release
10:01:41 AM web.1 |   - using code:     gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)
10:01:41 AM web.1 |  [GIN-debug] GET   /static/*filepath         --> github.com/heroku/go-getting-started/vendor/github…
10:01:41 AM web.1 |  [GIN-debug] HEAD  /static/*filepath         --> github.com/heroku/go-getting-started/vendor/github…
10:01:41 AM web.1 |  [GIN-debug] GET   /mark                     --> main.main.func1 (2 handlers)
10:01:41 AM web.1 |  [GIN-debug] Listening and serving HTTP on :5000
10:01:56 AM web.1 |  [GIN] 2016/04/08 - 10:01:56 | 404 |             0 | [::1]:50713 |   GET     /
10:02:15 AM web.1 |  [GIN] 2016/04/08 - 10:02:15 | 200 |             0 | [::1]:50714 |   GET     /mark
[WARN] Interrupted by User
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  SIGINT
10:02:32 AM web.1 Exited Abnormally
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y

c:\Go\src\github.com\heroku\go-getting-started>git add -A .
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Godeps/Godeps.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Godeps/Readme.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.

c:\Go\src\github.com\heroku\go-getting-started>git commit -m "Markdown demo dependency"
[master warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Godeps/Godeps.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
44f22d6] Markdown demo dependency
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Godeps/Godeps.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
 12 files changed, 5500 insertions(+), 7 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 vendor/github.com/russross/blackfriday/.gitignore
 create mode 100644 vendor/github.com/russross/blackfriday/.travis.yml
 create mode 100644 vendor/github.com/russross/blackfriday/LICENSE.txt
 create mode 100644 vendor/github.com/russross/blackfriday/README.md
 create mode 100644 vendor/github.com/russross/blackfriday/block.go
 create mode 100644 vendor/github.com/russross/blackfriday/html.go
 create mode 100644 vendor/github.com/russross/blackfriday/inline.go
 create mode 100644 vendor/github.com/russross/blackfriday/latex.go
 create mode 100644 vendor/github.com/russross/blackfriday/markdown.go
 create mode 100644 vendor/github.com/russross/blackfriday/smartypants.go

c:\Go\src\github.com\heroku\go-getting-started>git push heroku master
Counting objects: 21, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (17/17), done.
Writing objects: 100% (21/21), 39.28 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 21 (delta 3), reused 9 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Using set buildpack heroku/go
remote: -----> Go app detected
remote: -----> Checking Godeps/Godeps.json file.
remote: -----> Using go1.6
remote: -----> Running: go install -v -tags heroku ./...
remote: vendor/github.com/russross/blackfriday/block.go:19:2: cannot find package "github.com/shurcooL/sanitized_anchor_name" in any of:
remote:         /tmp/build_36053c1b0568bf24dcdcf90c103b1104/.heroku/go/src/github.com/heroku/go-getting-started/vendor/github.com/shurcooL/sanitized_anchor_name (vendor tree)
remote:         /app/tmp/cache/go1.6/go/src/github.com/shurcooL/sanitized_anchor_name (from $GOROOT)
remote:         /tmp/build_36053c1b0568bf24dcdcf90c103b1104/.heroku/go/src/github.com/shurcooL/sanitized_anchor_name (from $GOPATH)
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Go app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to lit-lake-35772.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/lit-lake-35772.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/lit-lake-35772.git'

c:\Go\src\github.com\heroku\go-getting-started>heroku open mark

c:\Go\src\github.com\heroku\go-getting-started>
```

Comment: What change did you make to Godeps.json when you typed `notepad Godeps/Godeps.json`? You aren't supposed to change that file after you run `godep save`...

Comment: I just looked `Godeps/Godeps.json` if `github.com/russross/blackfriday` reference was added or not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your commands didn't work but the problem is that the directory `vendor/github.com/shurcooL/sanitized_anchor_name` wasn't committed to your Git repo. The command `godep save ./...` should have added that repo to `Godeps/Godeps.json` and their files to `vendor/`, and the command `git add -A .` should have added them. But for some reason, they weren't added to your commit.

Try to run `godep save ./...` again and make sure the repository `github.com/shurcooL/sanitized_anchor_name` is added to your local `vendor/`. Then, run `git add`, `git commit` and `git push` as you already did. It should work :-)